# Uploading photos and adding their name to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that can enter a string (a name that has to be put in the database), and 2 for files. Those files have to be uploaded to a folder, and their names put in the sql database.

EDIT: The database part works, but i cant get it uploaded to the folder.

Here's my code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Uploading</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <form method="post" action="fototoevoegen.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p>
              Foto Name
            </p>

            <input type="text" name="fotonaam"/>
            <p>
              First Foto. Max size is 500kb.
            </p>

            <input type="hidden" name="size" value="5000000">
            <input type="file" name="photo"> 


         <p> Second Foto. Max size is 500kb.</p>
         <input type="hidden" name="size2" value="5000000">
            <input type="file" name="photo1"> 
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <input TYPE="submit" name="upload" title="Add data to the Database" value="Add Member"/>
          </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

And the PHP Code

```
         <?php



//This gets all the other information from the form
$name=$_POST['fotonaam'];


$picname1 = $_FILES["photo"]["name"];  

$picname2= $_FILES["photo1"]["name"];

//This is the directory where images will be saved
$target = "images/".$picname1;
$target2 = "images/".$picname2;

if((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) && (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name'], $target2)) )
{
Echo "Succes";
    // Connects to your Database
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ;
mysql_select_db("Manu") or die(mysql_error()) ;

//Writes the information to the database
mysql_query("INSERT INTO fotos (naamfoto,foto,fotothumb)
VALUES ('$name', '$picname1', '$picname2')") ;

//Tells you if its all ok
}
else {

//Gives and error if its not
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}





?>
```

Comment: many issues - (1) you have a stray `)` in your `$pic1=$_FILES['photo1']);`. (2) what are you expecting from `$pic` and `$pic1` when you insert them `... VALUES ('$name', '$pic', '$pic1') ...`? I assume you want to use `$_FILES['photo']['name']`/`$_FILES['photo1']['name']` instead. (3) you should do your `move_uploaded_file()` on **both** files before inserting into your database, to make sure they both exist first. (4) you are wide open to sql injection using `mysql_` without sanitizing your data.. Please take the time to update to `mysqli` or `PDO` and learn about prepared statements.

Comment: @Sean Please see my edit. PHP code updated, de db part works, but not the file upload itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to enter a file into database, not it's name.

When saving photo "**name**" to database table, it must be

```
    $picname1 = $_FILES["photo"]["name"];  // $picname1 contains name of photo 1

    $picname2= $_FILES["photo1"]["name"];  // $picname2 contains name of photo 2
```

**then add this to query**

```
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableName (naamfoto,foto,fotothumb)
    VALUES ('$name', '$picname1', '$picname2')") ;
```

And pls change

```
if((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) && (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name'], $target)) )
```

to

```
if((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target.$picname1)) && (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name'], $target.$picname2)) )
```

Comment: Thank you, after changing this, i still get the error move_uploaded_file() isnt working. Any ideas?

Comment: pls try to change $target = "images/" to $target = "images/".$picname1;

Comment: Works! Thank you VERY much for taking your time!